# How to render an image at its original size?

Tags: 8, theming, media

There are plenty of examples on the internet on how to render a styled image; for instance [this one from web omelette](https://www.webomelette.com/how-render-your-images-image-styles-drupal-8):

```
$render = [
    '#theme' => 'image_style',
    '#style_name' => 'thumbnail',
    '#uri' => 'public://my-image.png',
    // optional parameters
];
```

However I do not want to use an image style. I want to render the original untouched image. So I tried:

```
$render = [
    '#theme' => 'image_style',
    '#style_name' => NULL,
    '#uri' => 'public://my-image.png',
    // optional parameters
];
```

Which did not work. 
How do I render the original full-size image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use the `#theme` property `image` (which does not appear to be documented anywhere), but gives a valid image tag.

```
$render= [
  '#theme' => 'image',
  '#uri' => $file->getFileUri(),
];
```

Which becomes `<img src="/sites/default/files/image.png" alt="" />` once rendered.

Comment: For reference: [`drupal_common_theme()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21includes%21theme.inc/function/drupal_common_theme/8.4.x)

Comment: Ah great, I was already confused why it was not in `image_theme()`. Thanks :)

Comment: You can also use Drupal function realpath for it. $render= [ '#theme' => 'image', '#uri' => \Drupal::service('file_system')->realpath('public://my-image.png'),
];

Comment: Solution works, but any solution for the markup with height width and other attributes?

Comment: @VishalKumarSahu follow the link Clive posted above and find the supported variables for image. You can use `#height`.and more.

Comment: Yes adding `#attributes` array. But theme will not have the actual height width of the image as there is no `image_style` stored for this in the database unlike for `thumbnail` for example 100x100.

Comment: @VishalKumarSahu I do not understand what you want. If you always need specific sizes, use `'#theme' => 'image_style'`. I needed to show the original image (which can be controlled with css: `image { width: 100%; height: auto; }`). If you need to show the original image as well as with and height, ,you can pull them from the image class: [Drupal\Core\Image::getWidth()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Image!Image.php/function/Image%3A%3AgetWidth/8.2.x)